# AutoUpdater: 56K dialup connection, what normally is the upload speed?

Tags: performance, modem, auto-update

I'm building a auto updater and I need to know what kind of upload speeds people get on a 56K modem?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically 33.6 kbit/s upload = 4.2 kB/s[1].

From own experience, I would say half of that :)

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-T_V-Series_Recommendations#Simultaneous_transmission_of_data_and_other_signals

Answer (score 1):

Modems are generally not asymmetrical in their speeds, but I seem to remember that 56k was a special mode and upload was only @ 33k.

Wikipedia states the following in its article about [56k Modems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/56k_modem)

"The upload speed is 33.6 kbit/s if an analog voiceband modem is used (V.90), or 48.0 kbit/s using a digital modem (V.92)."

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem), the top (theoretical) speed is 48kbit/s.  This is assuming v.92, which a large percentage of users will not have.

Answer (score 0):

About 28.8K I believe ([source](http://www.56k.com/cons/downonly.shtml)).

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience I'll say about half the download speed.  For example I typically see 48k download speed at home and about 24k upload.